# how to bind raddropdown from different sources for different rows inside rad grid?

Tags: telerik-grid

How to bind the telerik rad containg raddropdown to bind from differrent sources in different rows.

```
Eg:raddropdown.dataSource=new list<string>{"apple","bat","cat"} in row 0
raddropdown.dataSource=new list<string>{"Dog","egg"}in row 1
```

Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is my dropdown inside a grid.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn 
    HeaderText="Employees" 
    SortExpression="emp_name" 
    UniqueName="emp_name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" 
        Text='<%#  Eval("emp_name") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="comboEmployees" 
            DataSourceID="odsEmployees"
            DataTextField="emp_name" 
            DataValueField="emp_id">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="comboEmployees" 
            DataSourceID="odsEmployees"
            DataTextField="emp_name" 
            DataValueField="emp_id">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Define a ObjectDataSource as follows.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="odsEmployees" 
    SelectMethod="getListOfEmployees"
    TypeName="ABC.DEF">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Create a code file as follows.

```
namespace ABC
{
    public class DEF{
        public List<tbl_employees> getListOfEmployees(){
            List<tbl_employees> employees = db.tbl_employees
                                                .Where(e => e.salary > 10000)
                                                .OrderBy(e => e.emp_name)
                                                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```